# Node.js: readfile reads just one line?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to parse a CSV file line by line.
However, when i output the contents of the file it shows just one line?

Here's the code:

```
fs.readFile('data.csv', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log(data)
    var tbl = data.split('\n'); 
    console.log(tbl.length);
})
```

First `console.log` outputs just one line of data while `tbl.length` outputs 1.

Why is it reading just one line instead of the entire file?

EDIT: Something strange going on, if i do `data.length` i get `580218`, which is much more than that one line i'm getting as output?

Comment: If you are open to using a module have a look at; https://www.npmjs.org/package/line-by-line

Comment: Have to ask: Does the file contain multiple lines? And, if it does, it may still not contain line-feeds (`\n`). Its [new lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations) might be represented by [other characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode), such as carriage returns (`\r`).

Comment: It does contain multiple lines, however, even console.log data outputs just one line instead of entire file?

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the file's contents? Maybe post the `data` stringified, which will escape many non-visible characters -- `console.log(JSON.stringify(data.substr(0, 1000)));`

Comment: Yup that did it, strigify! 
Please post it as an answer so i can approve it and give you points.

Comment: @R0b0tn1k Wait... for the rest of us, it's gone from "try this to see what's wrong" to "FIXED!". What was the issue, and how did that solve it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wanted to give Jonathan the chance to answer so he could get the points.

So couple of issues going on here.

1. Listing just one line from the CSV instead of the whole data.
   Turns out the JSON.strigify(string) did the trick.
   The extra lines or invalid characters may have caused it to output just one line, instead of the whole file.
2. The array.length for the split operation returned 1 line. I noticed later that the entire csv file was the [0] element of the array. Apparently something to do with the new lines in the string. 
   So i did stringily of the csv, and improved my split line a bit, and it worked.

Here's the modified code:

```
tbl = data.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"|");
        tbl = tbl.split("|")
        console.log(tbl.length);
```

Voila!